# Error al presionar un enlace de link en Flask

Tags: python, formularios, flask, routes

Tengo esta vista que es un login, sin ninguna funcionalidad aun pero tiene su formulario desde Flaskforms

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Login Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<body class="text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <h1>
                Please Login
            </h1>
            <br>
            {{ form.username.label() }}     

            {{ form.username(placeholder="User Name") }}
             
            <!-- etiqueta label es el texto normal y la del placeholder es la del campo  -->

            {{ form.password.label() }}
            {{ form.password( placeholder="Password") }}

            <br>


            <div>
               <h6>Do not have an account?</h6>
               <a href="{{ url_for('register_page') }}">Register</a>

               <!-- redirige a la pagina de registro -->
            </div>

            {{ form.submit() }}

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

{% endblock %}

sin embargo cuando le doy al enlace para ir a la pagina de registro me sale este error

```
TypeError
TypeError: The view function for 'register_page' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1526, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1545, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1701, in make_response
raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function for 'register_page' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

verifique que todas las vistas retornan y estuvieran bien escritas y si lo estan , no se que error pudiera ser porque lo google pero no sale mucho y ademas soy principiante.

las rutas con las que estoy trabajando son estas, la del registro que contiene el formulario de registro y valida que si la info que proporciono el usuario sea correcta lo guarda en la bdd y redirige a la pagina principal y en caso de error en los campos muestra el error si hay correo, usuario o clave invalida

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register_page():
    form = RegisterForm()         
    if form.validate_on_submit():     
        usuario = Users( username= form.username.data,      
        email = form.email.data,
        password= form.password1.data)   

        db.session.add(usuario)    
        db.session.commit()       
        return redirect(url_for('market_page'))    

    if form.errors != {}:     
        for err_msg in form.errors.values():   
            flash(f'hay un error : {err_msg}', category='danger')     
    
        return render_template('register.html',form=form)
```

la otra ruta es la del login que contiene el formulario de log in y retorna la vista de su html a login.html

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Comment: muestras tus rutas por favor

Comment: listo ya estan aagregadas @Boolean

Comment: pero no estas retornando nada en register, solo retornas en caso de que se presione el botón submit y en caso de errores si no me equivoco @anonymuus_gp